# Fill in text field data in jsp from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have data in a database where I want some of the text fields to be from the database. I create a method where it gets the data from the db. I have an open-account.jsp page where there is a form where the first name, last name, and email is already prefilled from the database so I used the get method from the servlet. When I try to send the data from the servlet to the jsp page, the field is null. I think it is not passing the data from the servlet to the jsp, I am not sure. Here is my code:

Database class:

```
public static ArrayList getUsers() 
    {
        ArrayList<Users> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            DBConnection.connectToDB();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM userlogin";

            stmt = DBConnection.conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));

                userList.add(user);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return userList;
    }
```

open-account.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Please fill in the details</h3>

    <form name="openAccount" action="OpenAccount" method="GET">
        <!-- in openaccount servlet, we will get the users info and fill some
        of the forms below for them -->

        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value= <%= request.getAttribute("Users.getFirstName()") %> > <br/><br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">  <br/><br/>

    </form>

    <form name="chooseAccount" action="OpenAccount" method="POST">  
        Select the type of account: 
        <select name="accounttype">
            <option>Checking</option>
            <option>Saving</option>
            <option>Money Market</option>
            <option>Credit Card</option>
        </select> <br/><br/>

        Please check the box if everything above is complete:
        Agree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Agree">
        Disagree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Disagree">

        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

OpenAccount serlvet

```
@WebServlet("/OpenAccount")
public class OpenAccount extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Users> userList = DBConnection.getUsers();

        request.setAttribute("Users", userList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("open-account.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In-order to get the list from `request`, you need to do casting in your jsp
- In your jsp, only single `User` instance is required, while your code passes on entire `ArrayList` of `User`.
- The code snippet is just for just for sake of understanding as what you will need to do to extract the required info.

  ```
  // make sure to import all required class
  Object users = request.getAttribute('Users');
  if(null != users && users instanceof ArrayList){
     ArrayList<User> userList = (ArrayList<User>)request.getAttribute('Users');
     for(User user: userList){
        out.println(user.getFirstName());
     }
  } else {
     out.println("No user records found.");
  }
  ```

P.S. Using jsp scriplets are bad practice, you can use JSTL instead.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look into your jsp page. Seem you just want to display a user profile instead of a user profiles list. So that you should revise your code like below:

Database class:

```
public static Users getUsers(String username) 
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        try
        {
            DBConnection.connectToDB();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM userlogin where username=?";

            stmt = DBConnection.conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1,username);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

open-account.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Please fill in the details</h3>

    <form name="chooseAccount" action="OpenAccount" method="POST">  

        <!-- in openaccount servlet, we will get the users info and fill some
        of the forms below for them -->

        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value= <%= request.getAttribute("firstname") %> > <br/><br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value= <%= request.getAttribute("lastname") %>> <br/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value= <%= request.getAttribute("email") %>>  <br/><br/>


        Select the type of account: 
        <select name="accounttype">
            <option>Checking</option>
            <option>Saving</option>
            <option>Money Market</option>
            <option>Credit Card</option>
        </select> <br/><br/>

        Please check the box if everything above is complete:
        Agree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Agree">
        Disagree <input type="radio" name="agree" value="Disagree">

        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

OpenAccount serlvet:

```
package com.javabycode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/OpenAccount")
public class OpenAccount extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {        
    Users users = DBConnection.getUsers();

    request.setAttribute("firstname", users.getFirstName());
    request.setAttribute("lastname", users.getLastName());
    request.setAttribute("email", users.getEmail());
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("open-account.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
     // do something
     //System.out.println(request.getAttribute("firstname"));
    }
}
```

I revise your example and run it on servlet container by referring to the [post](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/servlet-request-session-application-scope-attributes.html)

If you are just a beginner I strongly recommend you series of [Servlet 3 tutorial](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/java-servlet-tutorial-java-servlet-example.html)

Hope this help!